# my apps rejected due to ipv6 only requirement message

Tags: ios

My VPS server has IPV4 only. And my IOS apps rejected due to not support ipv6. So question is that, is it showing that  any server with IPV4 will not work with ios apps ? do we must purchase ipv6 server only. At present most of server have not ipv6 including hostgator, siteground etc. I think they also know that ios have changed rule from JUN-1. But still they have not IPV6. Is this error in ios code or in my vps server ?

Comment: get rid of your vps that only support ipv4

Comment: otherwise you can use e.g. AWS API Gateway as a proxy between your app and your server, but in this case, why having this server in the first place, move it to EC2 as well.

Comment: try adding app transport policy keys/values in application plist.

Comment: your server is fine, your application must support ipv6 only.

Answer (score 0):

No. You do not need to do anything with your server and your IPv4-only server will work fine. It's the client that you need to fix.